# Recover an array from its insertion indices

Tags: algorithms, arrays

An array is built starting with an empty array, and then a sequence of insertions:

1. insert $a_1$ at index $z_1=1$
2. insert $a_2$ at index $z_2$
3. insert $a_3$ at index $z_3$
4. ...

and so on.  When we insert element $a_i$ and index $z_i$ the result is that $a_i$ is now at index $z_i$, whereas everything before index $z_i$ is unchanged and everything after has its index increased by 1. (With one-based indexing) E.g., the sequence
$(3,1), (5,2), (1,2)$ gives $[3]$ then $[3,5]$ then  $[3,1,5]$. All of the instructions will make sense, i.e., $1 \leq z_i\leq i$.

My question is about how to calculate the final array. The naive approach would be to start with an empty array, and literally obey the instructions;  but in the language I program, insertions have a worst case time complexity of $O(\# $elements shifted$)$; if, for example, all the insertion indices were $1$, this would result in $O(N^2)$ time.

Supposing we have access to all the instructions simultaneously, how can we calculate the final array in faster than $O(N^2)$ time? I would be happy with a name if this problem is well studied. I did make the following (family of) observations:

1. the element which ends up at index 1 was the last one which arrived with index 1.
2. the element which ends up at index 2 arrived with index 1 or 2. If it arrived with index 2, then none came after it with either index 1 or 2. If it arrived with index 1, then exactly one came after it with index 1, after which came none with index 2.
3. the element which ends up at index 3 arrived with index 1, 2, or 3. If it arrived with index 3, then none came after it with index 1, 2 or 3. If it arrived with index 2, then exactly one element with index 1 or 2 followed it, then none after that with index 1, 2, or 3. If it arrived with index 1, then it was followed by one with index 1, then one with index 1 or 2, and then none after that with index 1, 2, or 3.

... and so on.
However I can't think of the algorithms or data structures that would make this information useful.

**Update: There are two $O(n\log n)$ solutions below: the first one, which I accepted, that uses an AVL tree, and one which I learned of afterward that uses a semgent tree, and is somewhat simpler.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Prelimiaries**

You can augment an AVL tree to support all the usual operations plus the following:

> Shift$(a,b)$ increases all keys $k \ge a$ by $b \ge 0$ in $O(\log n)$ time (where $n$ is the number of elements in the tree).

To do so add a value $x_v$ to each node $v$ in the tree. This value represents an offset to be added to all keys stored in the subtree rooted at $v$. The Search, Insert, and Shift operations, along with the required rotations can be implemented as follows (I won't be using the Delete operation, but it can also be implemented).

**Search**
The search operation work as usual except that you now keep track of the cumulative offset in the path from the current node to the root.

**Insert**
To insert a node with key $k$, use the search operation to find the position where a node with key $k$ would need to be placed and the cumulative offset $\overline{x}$ up to that point. Add a leaf in that position and store its key as $k - \overline{x}$. Perform the necessary rotations to rebalance the tree (see the sequel).

**Rotations** To perform a right rotation on $u$ let $v$ be its left child. 
"Push down" the offset of $u$ as follows: increment the stored key of $u$ by $x_u$, add $x_u$ to the offsets of the children of $u$, and set $x_u$ to $0$. Similarly, "push down" the offset of $v$. Perform the rotation as usual. Left rotations are symmetric.

**Shift$(a,b)$**. Find the node $u$ with key $a$ or, if no such node exists, find its successor (if the successor doesn't exist either, we are done). Increase the stored key of $u$ by $b$. If $u$ has a right child $v$ then increase $x_v$ by $b$ as well. Walk from $u$ to the root of the tree. Every time you walk to a vertex $w$ from its left child, increase the key of $w$ by $b$ and the offset $x_z$ of the right child $z$ of $w$ by $b$ (if $z$ exists).

---

**Solving your problem**

Keep an augmented AVL tree $T$ and consider the operations one at a time. At the end of the generic $i$-th step, the tree will contain $i$ nodes that collectively store the elements of the first $i$ operations. 
Each node $u$ is associated with one element of the array. The key of $u$ is exactly the position of $u$'s element in the array, as of the $i$-th operation, while the element's value is stored as satellite data in $u$.

When the operation $(a_i, z_i)$ is to be processed do a Shift$(z_i, 1)$ operation on $T$. Then, insert a new node with key $z_i$ and satellite data $a_i$ in $T$.

At the end of the process you can traverse the tree and recover the final position (the node's key) of each array element (the node's satellite data).

The total time required is $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: Your answer has forced me to learn about AVL trees which I have put off for some time.  I will need some time before I can try this idea.

Comment: If I'm getting the point of this, the keys of this tree are meant to be unique (whereas the insertion indices in the original problem may be repeated), so that at the end of every step, we could traverse the tree and the element with key 1 is first, the element with key 2 is second, etc.  However, if I follow the steps of this algorithm applied to say, $(5,1), (6,2), (7,3)$, I would need a right rotation at $5$ after insertion of $7$, and the stored key of $5$ becomes $2$, the same as the key of $6$ in your rotation "push-down" step, violating uniqueness.

Comment: After inserting $(5,1),(6,2),(7,3)$ (but before rebalancing), the tree is unbalanced to the right. All the offsets are $0$. The key stored in the root $r$ is $1$ (with value $5$), the key stored in the right child $u$ of $r$ is $2$ (with value $6$), and the key stored in the right child $v$ of $u$ is $3$ (with value $7$). To rebalance the tree a **left** rotation rooted at $r$ is needed. The push-down step is a no-op since all the offsets are $0$. The tree from the rotation is balanced and has $u$ as the root, $r$ as $u$'s left child, and $v$ as $u$'s right child. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: Ok, I meant to say left rotation and furthermore I chose an example that works fine.  I've written out the steps precisely for the sequence of insertions $(1,2,2,2)$ and it shows that you can end up with duplicated keys, using your algorithm:  https://imgur.com/a/eFKZGFg

I think it might be true that the key+offset is unique in the tree, but BST requires unique keys.  On the other hand, if you were to propagate the change from a new +1 offset, that could be O(n) time as you would need to update the keys of all succeeding values.

Comment: You seem not to be taking offsets into account when looking at keys. From my answer: "add a value $x_v$ to each node $v$ in the tree. This value represents an offset to be added to all keys stored in the subtree rooted at $v$."  In your final tree node $c$ has key $3+ x_c = 3+0=3$, node $a$ has key $1+ x_a + x_c  =1+0+0=1$, node $d$ has key "2 + x_d + x_a + x_c = 2+0+0+0", and node $b$ has key $3 + x_b + x_c = 3+1+0 = 4$. The state of the tree seems correct to me. Somehow you're not taking into account $x_b$ when looking at the nodes in the subtree rooted at $b$.

Comment: Notice that the whole point of these offset is to avoid explicitly propagating the change in keys to all the nodes in the corresponding subtrees (which, as you say, would require $O(n)$ time in the worst case). The above approach allows every operation to be supported in $O(\log n)$ time since only a logarithmic number of keys and offsets need to be changed after each operation. When you do the final in-order visit of the tree you can just keep track (in constant time per node) of the sum of the offsets from the current node to the root of the tree. The **overall** time of the visit is $O(n)$.

Comment: One general problem I have with not leaving the tree a BST at the end of every step is that it's not even clear that these operations are defined.  Could you state clearly (in a way that would be possible to prove) what the relevant invariant is, which is preserved at the end of every step?   Something like "after step $i$, the key plus offset $u + x_u$ equals the index in the array so far, and the tree is (a balanced BST ordered by unique keys from 1 to $i$)"?   (latter part is not true as it stands)

Comment: Ok, here's a sequence of operations that leaves it not a BST in any sense that I can define easily:  after insertions (1,2,2,2), we both agree the above picture is how the algo left the tree. Now we insert e at index 4. We first perform SHIFT(4,1); this locates node $(3∣1)^b$ and changes it to $(4∣1)^b$; then walks back up to the root (never from left child). Then we perform the insert of 4, which locates the left slot of $(4∣1)^b$ as the place of insertion; we insert $(4−1∣0)^e$ there, where 1 was the cumulative offset. No rotations necessary. Now there are two nodes $(3\mid 0)$.

Comment: Given a vertex $u$ in the tree, let $s_u$ be the "partial key" currently stored at $u$ and $x_u$ be the offset currently stored at $u$. Define $X(u)$ as the sum of all the values $x_v$ over all the ancestors $v$ of $u$ (where $u$ is an ancestor of itself). Define the *effective key* of $u$ as $k_u := s_u + X(u)$.
Finally, define $V_u$ to be the value stored in vertex $u$.

Comment: After the $i$-th step, the current tree $T$ satisfies the following properties:

1) $\{k_u\;:\;u \mbox{ is a node of } T\}=\{1,\dots,i\}$.

2) $T$ is an AVL tree w.r.t. the effective keys: (2a) if $u$ and $v$ are nodes of $T$ and $u$ lies in the left (resp. right) subtree of $v$, then $k_u<k_v$ (resp. $k_u>k_v)$; and (2b) the balance factor of every node in $T$ is in $\{0,1,-1\}$.

3) For any $j=1,\dots,i$, let $u$ be the unique node in $T$ with $k_u = j$, $V_u$ is the value in the $j$-th position in the array obtained by performing only the the first $i$ operations.

Comment: Your description of the SHIFT$(4,1)$ operation during the insertion of $e$ at index $4$ doesn't match its definition. 
The SHIFT$(a,b)$ operation says "Find the node $u$ with [effective] key $a$ or, if no such node exists, find its successor (if the successor doesn't exist either, we are done)."

There is no node $u$ such that $k_u = 4$, therefore you look for the successor of $4$ in the tree (i.e., for the node $v$ with smallest $k_v$ among the ones in $\{ v \; : \; k_v > 4\}$).  Since there is no such successor (the above set is empty), this SHIFT$(4,1)$ operation is a no-op.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Regarding your last comment, $(3\mid 1)^b$ in the picture would have effective key 4 according to your definition of effective key (3 + the sum of offsets above and including the node, which is 1). So we would still change it to $(4\mid 1)^b$, and the insertion would still result in a $(3\mid 0)$ node.  However since we are dealing with effective keys now, there isn't a violation of uniqueness with this particular sequence.  Here it is, again: https://imgur.com/a/eFKZGFg

Comment: Sigh, you are right. My apologies. I had missed the offset of $1$ on node $b$. Anyway, as you point out, SHIFT$(4,1)$ will increase the key of $b$ to $5$ (represented as $4+1$). This leaves the tree with the following set of effective keys $\{1,2,3,5\}$. Now you can safely insert $4$. Sorry again.

Comment: I'm going to try to work out a proof tomorrow (which assuming it's correct shouldn't be difficult with all the definitions in hand).  Thanks for all the details

Comment: Ok actually I was able to verify things just now. I clarified what to do upon rotations (what you had written should be ordered as "push down v" THEN "push down u") but other than that everything looks right.  I posted the proof of your answer, as another answer.  Thanks for all of your help, I wouldn't have thought of anything like this myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101239/discussion-between-steven-and-user111398).

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation of the correctness of Steven's answer.  Of course I would be interested if anyone came up with something simpler but it is a great solution as it stands.

Define the *effective key at a node* to be the node's label + the offsets of all nodes on the (inclusive) path from itself to the root. Our inductive hypothesis is that after processing the $i$-th insertion, we have $i$ nodes with effective keys $1,2,\ldots, i$, in a balanced BST ordered with respect to effective keys.  Physically, the effective key for the node associated with element $a$ equals the current index of element $a$ in our array.

Algorithm, at step $(a_i,z_i)$. By hypothesis, the tree of size $i-1$ has nodes with effective keys $1$ through $i-1$.  In the case $z_i=i$ we just locate the unique node with effective key $i-1$ and insert $i$ with offset $0$ as a right child.  In the other case, $z_i<i$, we perform SHIFT($z_i,1$);  the way that it is defined means that SHIFT$(z_i,1)$ increases the effective key of nodes $z_i, z_i+1, \ldots, i-1$ by precisely 1 and leaves all lesser keys unchanged.  To insert the effective key $z_i$, we either put it in the left slot of $z_i+1$, or the rightmost descendant of $(z_i+1).left$; in either case, we store it with label $z_i-(\text{cumulative offset})$ and offset 0. Both SHIFT and this insertion happen in $O(\log N)$ time. Now we have effective keys $1$ through $i$ reprsented in a BST.

So insertions do the right thing to effective keys.  Now to keep the BST balanced (and so achieve $\log n$ complexity) AVL and red-black trees use rotations. It is known that rotations preserve the orderings in a BST. The problem here is that the effective keys are calculated using the offsets leading up to the root. A rotation may change the offsets seen on the way from a node to the root, since it may change the path from that node to the root. For instance if the node $v$ is rotated up into $u$'s position, then the offset $x_u$ that would have been counted in the path from root to $v$, is no longer encountered, while the offset $x_v$ would now be counted in the calculation for $u$. To see how we might do rotations without messing up the effective keys, we introduce the "push-down" operation on a node $u$. Let $v_1, v_2$ be its children.  The push down on $u$ increments $x_{v_1}$ and $x_{v_2}$ by $x_u$; increments $u$ by $x_u$; and lastly sets $x_u=0$.

During a rotation (let's say right rotation for definiteness) about node $u$ with left child $v$, we first push down $u$, then push down $v$, and finally rotate as usual:  it can be seen by checking all modified parts of the tree, that the effective keys remain the same after rotation:
[image]
(in the above picture, we'd check that the effective keys corresponding to nodes $v,u$ and subtrees $R,S,T$ are unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

I recently learned a weird trick to solve the problem in $O(n\log n)$. It appeared in [a comment on a codeforces blog](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/46102?#comment-305678) and seems to be well(?) known among competitive programmers. It puzzles me why it works, but I will update this answer with a proof if and when I figure it out. Below is a description of the procedure: (**Update**: proof below)

We are sequentially inserting $n$ elements, with the $i$ element at index $z_i$ and trying to find the final indices. Initialize an array $s[\cdot]$ of length $n$, all zeros. Begin with the $n$-th (final) element and work our way backwards to the 1st element. To start, find the $z_n$-th "$0$" of $s$, counted from the right, and change it from $0$ to $1$. The final position of the $n$-th element is just $z_n$, since no elements come after to "bump" its position. We say its "offset" is $0$.

In general, for the $i$-th element; we locate the $z_i$-th "$0$" of $s$ from the right and change it to "$1$"; let the $i$-th offset equal the $\#$ of $1$s strictly to the right of the new "$1$". Then the final index of the $i$-th element is $z_i$ plus its offset.

Example: Insertions at 1,2,1,1. Initialize $s=[1,1,1,1]$

- Insertion of the 4th element at index 1: $s=[0,0,0,0] \rightarrow [0,0,0,1]$. Offset $= 0$, since there are no $1$s to the right. Final index $=1+0$.
- Insertion of the 3rd element at index 1: $s=[0,0,0,1]\rightarrow [0,0,1,1]$. Offset $=1$, since there was one $1$ to the right. Final index $=1+1$.
- Insertion of the 2nd element at index 2: $s=[0,0,1,1]\rightarrow [1,0,1,1]$. Offset $= 2$, since there were two $1$s to the right. Final index $=2+2$.
- Insertion of the 1st element at index 1: $s=[1,0,1,1]\rightarrow [1,1,1,1]$. Offset $= 2$, since there were two $1$s to the right. Final index = 3.

Using a segment tree (or possibly a fenwick tree), queries of the type "count the number of $1$s in the range $[k,n]$ of $s$" is a standard range-sum query and can be answered in $O(\log n)$.

Queries of the type "find the $j$-th $0$ in $s$ from the right", can also be answered in $O(\log n)$ time with what is essentially a binary search of the tree starting at the root. First suppose that we have a segment tree with every element of $s$ flipped ($0$s as $1$s and vice versa). In this case we could find the $j$-th $1$ from the right by identifying the rightmost $[k,n]$ such that $s[k]+s[k+1]+\cdots+s[n]=j$. The latter problem can be accomplished via a binary search starting from the root. And in this case the desired $1$ is found at $s[k]$.

Finally, the updates to individual elements of $s$ (changing a $0$ to a $1$) can be done in $O(\log n)$ time.

---

**Proof of correctness**: 
Denote $b_i:=$ the number of elements which bump the $i$-th element; observe that every bump causes the index to rise by $1$. So the final index of the $i$-th element is $z_i+b_i$.

> **Lemma: Let $j>i$. Then the $j$-th element bumps the $i$ iff $z_j+b_j<z_i+b_i$**.

The direction $\impliedby$ is basically obvious due to the observation about the final index; for $\implies$, assuming $j$ bumps $i$, we recognize two cases: (1) $z_j\leq z_i$; note that anything that bumps $j$ also bumps $i$; furthermore $j$ bumps $i$, so we have $b_i\geq b_j+1$, hence the result. (2) $z_j>z_i$; in this case we must have that the $i$-th element was bumped at least $z_j-z_i$ times before seeing the $j$-th element (otherwise the $j$-th element would have been inserted to the right of the $i$-th). Then the $j$-th element arrives, bumping the $i$-th. Then anything that bumps the $j$-th element also bumps the $i$-th. So we have $b_i \geq z_j-z_i+1+b_j$, proving the result.

Now initialize an array $S'$ of length $n$ with all $0$s. Starting from $i=n$ and going down to $i=1$, we set $S'[z_i+b_i] := 1$. And by the lemma above, we have that $b_i = \#\{k>z_i+b_i \colon S[k]=1\}$.

Now in the algorithm, define $d_i =$ the offset (i.e. the "number of $1$s to the right" at the step where we process the $i$-th element). Observe that $b_n = d_n$ and that otherwise, the sequences $b_i$ and $d_i$, from $i=n$ to $1$, are built following the same rules; in particular setting the $z_j$-th zero of $s$, counted from the right, is equivalent to setting the $(z_j+d_j)$-th element of $s$. This shows that $d_i=b_i$ for all $i$.