# Red-Black tree with index

Tags: data-structures, trees, red-black-trees

I want to create a Red-Black Tree, with 2 values, (index, value) and I want to insert into the RB_tree based on the index.

So if I have the function: $\text{insert}(root, value, index)$ it will insert the value at $index$. However, because I insert based on the other indexes, if I insert at the index $1$ let's say, and I have already inserted at that index, then I would have to add to all the other node's indexes $+1$. The insert function is used only with valid indexes so, $index\in[0, size(RB\_tree)]$. What should I do to keep the insertion $O(\log n)$ and still have the indexes?

Comment: See the first part of the answer to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116897/recover-an-array-from-its-insertion-indices/116904?noredirect=1#comment247444_116904). The answer is about AVL trees but the same approach should work for general Red-Black trees. When you want to insert an element with index $i$ you can first add $1$ to all the keys that are greater than or or equal to $i$ (by using the Shift$(i,1)$ operation), and then insert the element as usual.

Comment: @Steven and the complexity for that, would be still $O(\log n)?$

Comment: @Steven and for that operation "push down", for the $v$ node would mean do the same thing but for the $v$ node, and the meaning of "left operation are symmetric" means that I should also do $push\_down$ but in the left rotation, right?

Comment: Yes, all the complexities would still be $O(\log n)$ in the worst case, including that of the Shift operation. Yes, "push down" for $v$, means to do exact same thing that you did for node $u$ but for $v$ (add $x_v$ to the offsets of $v$'s children and to $v$'s key, then $x_v$ to $0$). Left rotations are symmetric means that you just swap the role of $v$ (that in the right rotation was $u$'s left child) to be the right child of $u$. Then, you proceed similarly: "push down" the offset on $u$, "push down" the offset on $v$ (so that $x_u = x_v = 0$), and perform the left rotation as usual.

Comment: @Steven and one more thing, when do I actually increment that field $x_v$ that will cumulate in search and insert?

Comment: The offsets $x_v$ are incremented during the Shift$(a,b)$ operation. Specifically those of the right children of the nodes that you encounter as you walk from the predecessor/successor of the node with key $a$ towards the root, provided that you are coming from their left sibling.

Comment: @Steven so what i should just do is: implement s normal red black tree, modify rotations as explained and implement shift operation + everytime I insert a node first call Shift(i, 1) and everything should be fine right?

Comment: Yes. And be careful to take the offsets into accounts when you insert and search for nodes.

Comment: @Steven I already kind of did that but something goes wrong, can I show you somehow what I tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100992/discussion-between-steven-and-c-cristi).

Comment: @Steven can you help me with something at deletion? And also concatenation?