Is there an algorithm for rearranging a set in a specific way while optimizing for minimum amount of moves?
Say I have an array that goes like [ a, c, b, d ] and I want it rearranged as [ d, c, a, b ]. The only type of change I'm allowed to make is plucking an element from one place and inserting it into another. Also, the array stays continuous with no empty indices, for example if I pluck c from [ a, c, b, d ] it becomes [ a, b, d ] until I reinsert c.
Is there an algorithm to figure out a minimal sequence of such changes in order to complete the transformation?

Is your problem similar to this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156277/producing-moves-to-permute-one-array-to-another

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086670600030X seem relevant

If you look at the set of elements you do not move, this set must form a common subsequence of the input string and the target string. Therefore, the number of elements you do not move cannot be longer than a longest common subsequence. On the other hand, all the other elements can be moved to their correct places in one move. Therefore the algorithm goes like this:

find a longest common subsequence
move all the other elements

Finding a longest common subsequence can be done in quadratic time.
